# Angular save searchParams and page refresh

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm in a search page that display some users, there is a search bar with some filters and these filters will be used to execute a `GET` request to the server with HttpClient.
What I'm not able to find is a best practice to store these parameters on the query string (to be able to bookmark the search) and even if the page is refreshed, they will be kept in the Url. 
What I'm doing now is:

- Execute the search request
- `this.router.navigate([], { queryParams: { search: searchParams }});` where searchParams is a string that contains all the parameters used for the search.
- Storing these searchParams everytime they are updated in a Store(redux)
- On the `ngOnInit` of the component, I'm using a `route:ActivatedRoute` to read the params from the snapshot of the route like this `route.snapshot.queryParams.search` to retrieve, if there are the searchParams, and use them to execute the new call when reloading the page.

What is happening is that when I'm reloading the page after having applied some filters, the page reload correctly reading the parameters from the url, but it's not able to set them again in the queryString, so if I reload again, the page will have no filters applied.

With this solution above I'm pretty much close to a "solution" but I don't think that is the best way to do this, there must be a smarter way to do this.

Comment: When you reload the page with filters applied, you get the desired search result. Fine, but why are you loosing those filters (query params) from the url? That should not happen. URL should still be the same.

Comment: @AmitChigadani I don't know, after reload I'm using again `this.router.navigate([], { queryParams: { search: searchParams }});` but it is not able to set the value in the Url. and it remains .../users without the searchParams at the end